# Is there a method to preserve order when matrix multiplying in Mathematica?

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I know that commutativity can be preserved in Mathematica by using

**

i.e.

a*b can get printed as b a
but if I use a**b then it will always be printed as a b.

However, I am not able to implement this for elements of a matrix when multiplying matrices.

Answer (score 4):

```
dot[A_?VectorQ, B_?VectorQ] := Total[MapThread[NonCommutativeMultiply, {A, B}]];
dot[A_?MatrixQ, B_?MatrixQ] := Outer[dot, A, Transpose[B], 1];

A = Array[a, {4, 3}];
B = Array[b, {3, 2}];
dot[A, B]
```

Comment: How can it be implemented for Outer product of vectors?

Comment: `kroneckerproduct[a_?VectorQ, b_?VectorQ] := Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, a, b]`